# Folders aren't loading/showing up at all. (Could this be a virus?)

Tags: windows-10, memory

I've been having this problem for a while now. If I restart my PC it's fine, but if I'm on my PC for long enough it starts to do this and my PC isn't even using much power. I'm currently having the issue, and I'm using about 15% of my CPU, 40% of my memory and 2% of my GPU.

Specs:

GPU: GTX 1050ti
  CPU: Core i5-4570
  RAM: 16GB DDR3
  My PC isn't even a year old yet.

Folders aren't loading/showing up at all. Could this be a virus?

[image: folders]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Task Manager:

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: Yes, could be a virus. Make a full scan with Avast or, better, with [Kaspersky](https://www.kaspersky.com/free-antivirus). In addition, you should take a look to that "ops browser" that has several entries in your task manager

Comment: thanks but that obs is a recording software i use (a lot of big streamers do to) its just a free program that is 100% safe

Comment: i used kaspersky and i did a full scan on my pc nothing came up i have malwarebytes avast and kaspersky all on my system and nothing comes up its all clear i think it may be a a memory problem or my graphics card or something i don't really know